# Is there any guide on using Redis for FIFO Job Queuing?

Tags: redis

Hello i am very very new to Redis and have been reading up on what it can do.
I have intention of using Redis to push files that have been uploaded to my web server to another machine which execute the process.

However i am just going to ask if there is any helpful guide anyone has to help me understand the whole process and give it a shot.

LPOP 
RPUSH
JSON

i understand the process revolves around these commands, hence anyone with Redis Queuing experience can provide me a newbie guide?

Comment: try http://www.rediscookbook.org/implement_a_fifo_queue.html or http://peter-hoffmann.com/2012/python-simple-queue-redis-queue.html just for python

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the "Reliable queue" example on this page: http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

The idea is to add commands to the queue using `LPUSH`, then having the other machine `RPOP` them (or `BRPOP`) when it starts processing them. The *better* idea is to actually `BRPOPLPUSH` the commands to another key (the "commands curently being processed" queue) so that if your worker node crashes, you don't lose information.

Comment: Sorry that i am asking as stupid question but, if i have a redis server, i do need a redis client on another machine to receive the data?

Comment: A Redis client is any program that connects to your Redis server. So you'll probably have one (or more) that adds commands to the queue, and one (or more) that read commands from the queue.

Comment: As per Redis 6.2.0, RPOPLPUSH is considered deprecated. Please prefer LMOVE in new code.